# Send requests through TOR using httr package

Tags: r, tor, httr

I want to send GET requests using Tor proxy and R httr package. I have found the simple code here: https://gist.github.com/jeroen/5127c288f8914bdb20be, but when I try it:

```
library(httr)
GET("https://httpbin.org/get", use_proxy("socks5://localhost:9050"))
```

I got an error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to localhost port 9050: Connection refused
```

I have opened the tor browser before snding executing request.
I have also tried with port 9001.

Answer (score 0):

It works with 9150 port

```
library(httr)
GET("https://httpbin.org/get", use_proxy("socks5://localhost:9150"))
```